# Manual slid show in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried like this:

I have image sliding automatically but now I tried Manual image sliding but I don't know about Manual sliding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="wood.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="spree.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="pic01.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="pic02.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="pic03.jpg">
   </div>

</div>
<style>

#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

#slideshow li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

#slideshow li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

#slideshow img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }

</style>

</body>

<script>
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')

    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

</script>

</html>
```

Above is done Automatically sliding.

Anyone can give me idea about Manual sliding and then please tell me what changes I should do in my code?

Comment: I noticed jQuery isn't included, did you include <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @AkiraDawson thks for Reply i am new to JQuery so please help i place that line but images are not slid

Comment: What do you mean by "it is displaying one by one image but I want slideshow"? Do you want the slides to slide/move in and out one after another instead of fading? Then you would need to place them side by side in a row and move the whole row each time by the width of the next slide.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you have include jquery and define a document ready event.
So your slid.js will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);

})
```

and before closing body tag you have to insert jquery link and link to your slid.js.

```
<body>
 <div id="slideshow">
   <div><img src="first.jpg"></div>
   <div><img src="sce.jpg"></div>
   <div> Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything</div>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slid.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want your images slide right to left your whole code will be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    overflow:hidden;
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 260px; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="slideshow">
   <div><img src="first.jpg"></div>
   <div> <img  src="sce.jpg"></div>
   <div> Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything</div>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first').css({'left':'10px'})
    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .animate({'left':'260px'},1000)
        .next()
        .animate({'left':'10px'},1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);

})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this can help you, by.